# Meteor.js é um bom framework para desenvolvimento ágil?

Tags: node.js, meteor, meteorjs

Gostaria de saber se o `Meteor.js` é um bom *framework* para desenvolvimento web. Ultimamente estou realizando algumas pesquisas e não encontro muitas fontes de material recentes. Não vejo força nas comunidades brasileiras a cerca de uns 8 meses, e isto me deixou intrigado, pois não sei por qual motivo isto aconteceu.

Desde já agradeço quem tenha dedicado seu tempo para dar atenção a minha pregunta.